# Merging sorted arrays stored as linked lists

Tags: algorithms, arrays

I have $k$ sorted arrays stored as linked lists. I need an algorithm to merge them into one single sorted array, also stored as a linked list. How can I do that?

My Code:

```
Function merge(A[k]) 
Begin:

// A is array of list to merge.
Array result;
temp //array to save element in each list 
For (i=0:i<k:i++):
Temp.add(A[i].head.value);

While(result.size<n):
 Minvalue, index = temp.pop()
 Result.add(minvalue)
 Value = 0
 If( A[index].head.next==Null):
   Value = maxInt 
 Else :
  A[index].head = A[index].head.next
  Value = A[index].head.key Temp.add(value)
 Return result;
 
End
```

Comment: I would merge each 2 and continue as I'm in an intermediate step of *merge sort*. If I knew the lengths of the lists in advance, I might think for a while whether to pick longer lists to be merged together or choose one small and one large, or it doesn't matter at all? no of comparisons always *O(n log K)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $k = 2$, you can use the classical *merge* routine of Merge Sort, which fits the linked list data structure well. In this routine, you repeatedly compare the smallest elements of both arrays, adding the smaller one to the new array, and removing it from its own array.

You can use the same idea for general $k$. Instead of comparing the $k$ smallest elements at every step, you can use a priority queue that stores the smallest elements of each array, thus improving the running time of every step from $\Theta(k)$ to $O(\log k)$.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I think i get the runtime as O(k) and not logk

Comment: Use a heap instead of an array to store the $k$ smallest elements at every step.

Comment: yes. First i construct heap temp with first elements of all lists and it has same size of number of lists. Then i pop min value and it’s index in temp heap. Add min value to array A. Then get next value in list . And add this value to heap temp.
And i keep looping for above steps until n. Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Operations on a heap take logarithmic time.